# Why is this generator not working in Python?

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to return all product reviews by user name.

I have written a generator function but on coming back to it, it does not work and returns a syntax error:

```
def find_reviews(username):
    for u in reviewers_dicts:
        if u['username'] == username:
            review = u['reviews']
            yield review
            print(review)
            next

find_reviews('krpz1113')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
<generator object find_reviews at 0x0000016C852CECF0>
```

Comment: That's not an error, if you want to see the result encapsulate it in `list()`

Comment: That's how generator works. Its not the error, rather the object. you can get the result `next(find_reviews)`

Comment: the output you show does not match the code snippet. That is representation of generator object being printed.

Comment: @buran The Python shell outputs the return objects of functions if you call them, so the user could have typed this code into the Python shell.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin, if this is the case there would be `>>>`  and `...` in the code and we should not be asked to guess (do you really think they removed the `>>>`?). In any case, the code snippet is incomplete - `reviewers_dicts` is not present.

Comment: Thanks @Irfanuddin that's a helpful response

Comment: I'm in Jupyter. When I run the code I get the output given.

Comment: btw, that bare `next` after `print(review)` makes no sense and does nothing

Answer (score 2):

`<generator object find_reviews at 0x0000016C852CECF0>` Is not an error, but a generator object (As it says in the output). To get your desired result, you can use `next()`. For example:

```
def func(x):
    num = 0
    while num < x:
        yield num
        num += 1
b = func(10)
# Use these to get an individual value
next(b) 
next(b)
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Alternatively, you can call the `list` method on your generator object:

```
def func(x):
    num = 0
    while num < x:
        yield num
        num += 1
b = func(10)
# Use this to get a list
lst = list(b)
print(lst)
```

or iterate through a for loop:

```
def func(x):
    num = 0
    while num < x:
        yield num
        num += 1
b = func(10)

for item in b:
    print(item)
```